# Python - Django. DEF function from view aren't showing up after using in the templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a small problem where i unfrotunately cant understand why it happens.

I want to use my DEF defined in view in my templates within the for cycle.
If i put it just like this (not loading functions from view) it works fine:

```
{% for i in "1234567" %}
    <option value={{i}}> {{i}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

BUT if i try to load my function defined in view in this 2 different ways:

```
def skuska(request):
    template = loader.get_template('bc_python\templates\event_list.html')
    questions = ['name', 'quest', 'favorite color']
    context = {
        'items':questions
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

OR:

```
def skuska_2(request):
    questions = ['name', 'quest', 'favorite color']
    return render_to_response('event_list.html',{ 'items_n': questions })
```

AND then i am trying to call it in a for cycle in my template:

```
{% for post in items %}
    <p>{{ post }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

AND the second :

```
{% for palo in items_n %}
    <p>{{palo}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It doesn't not do anything. No error state but on the other side no result on the screen.
My Template file can be viewed here [event_list.html](https://paste.ofcode.org/3bwiMUYUb94Pxski2BNhZzZ)

Could you please explain me how to solve this "issue". I am stucked on this place already for days and cant find any suitable resolution here or on any other forum. If you need additional informations just let me know please.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try  `from django.template import Context` `context = Context({ 'items':questions})` and `return HttpResponse(template.render(context))` in your view

Comment: I'm not sure why you are calling this variable a "DEF function". It is not a function, and it is not defined by "DEF"; it is a variable inside your function.

Comment: @doru not working :-/. It doesn't shows any error message but still not showing the content of "questions" array when i load the page event_list.html. Could there be any problem with other .py files?

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render

    def skuska(request):
        questions = ['name', 'quest', 'favorite color']
        return render(
            request,
            'event_list.html',
            {'items': questions}
        )
```

urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import url
from views import skuska

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^skuska/$', skuska, name='skuska'),
]
```

In template:

```
{% for post in items %}
    <p>{{ post }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Navigate to your-site/skuska

Try also to clear browser cache or reload page with Ctrl + F5

Comment: I tried but doesn't solve my problem. Still not showing when i load my web page. Any other things that i could add?

Comment: I update my answer including urls.py file. I see in your template that you extend base.html so it is part of login-register templates? So maybe the problem is related to this. Post your urls.py where view is related to specific url

Comment: OK i managed to figure it out. The problem was with the structure of the folders. It was wrong and because of that i was not able to use the variables from view.